# Concurrent Modification Exception in Processing Sketch

Tags: java, processing, concurrentmodification

I'm working on modifying the Attraction2D example from the [Toxiclibs library](http://toxiclibs.org/) to be controlled by gestures from a Leap Motion sensor, as opposed to the mouse in the example.

I'm doing all my gesture recognition in an Open Frameworks app, and sending that over OSC.

When a `Gesture 0` event occurs, I call the method below to remove the `gestureAttractor` from the `physics` object:

```
void resetAttraction() {
  if (gestureAttractor != null){
      physics.removeBehavior(gestureAttractor);
      println("ATTRACTOR NULL");
     } else {
        println("not null");
     }
}
```

If a `Gesture 1` event occurs, I call this method to create a new `gestureAttractor`, and add it back to the `physics` object:

```
void addAttraction(){ 
   if (gestureAttractor == null) { 
       println("ATTRACTOR NULL"); 
       position1.set(340, 191); 
       gestureAttractor = new AttractionBehavior2D(position1, 250, 0.9f); 
       physics.addBehavior(gestureAttractor); 
   } else { 
       println("not null"); 
   } 
}
```

What seems to happen consistently is whenever the gesture state changes, I'll get a `ConcurrentModificationException` crash at `physics.update();` in the `draw` method.

I'm sure it has something to do with the way the lifecycle of these objects are handled, but I haven't been able to determine anything yet - anyone have any ideas?

Below is the entirety of the sketch:

```
import toxi.geom.*;
import toxi.physics2d.*;
import toxi.physics2d.behaviors.*;

import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscP5 oscP5;

int NUM_PARTICLES = 750;

VerletPhysics2D physics;
//AttractionBehavior2D mouseAttractor;
AttractionBehavior2D gestureAttractor;


//Vec2D mousePos;
Vec2D position1;


boolean isGestureAttractorAdded;

void setup() {
  size(680, 382,P3D);
  // setup physics with 10% drag
  physics = new VerletPhysics2D();
  physics.setDrag(0.05f);
  physics.setWorldBounds(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
  // the NEW way to add gravity to the simulation, using behaviors
  physics.addBehavior(new GravityBehavior2D(new Vec2D(0, 0.15f)));

  // start oscP5, listening for incoming messages at port 12000 
  oscP5 = new OscP5(this, 6000);

  position1 = new Vec2D(340, 191);

  addAttraction();

  //gestureAttractor = new AttractionBehavior2D(position1, 250, 0.9f);
  //physics.addBehavior(gestureAttractor);
}

void addParticle() {
  VerletParticle2D p = new VerletParticle2D(Vec2D.randomVector().scale(5).addSelf(width / 2, 0));
  physics.addParticle(p);
  // add a negative attraction force field around the new particle
  physics.addBehavior(new AttractionBehavior2D(p, 20, -1.2f, 0.01f));
}

void draw() {
  background(255,0,0);
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  if (physics.particles.size() < NUM_PARTICLES) {
    addParticle();
  }
  physics.update();
  for (VerletParticle2D p : physics.particles) {
    ellipse(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  //position1 = new Vec2D(mouseX, mouseY);
   //create a new positive attraction force field around the mouse position (radius=250px)
  //gestureAttractor = new AttractionBehavior2D(position1, 250, 0.9f);
  //physics.addBehavior(gestureAttractor);

  //println(physics.behaviors);
}

void mouseDragged() {
  // update mouse attraction focal point
  //position1.set(mouseX, mouseY);
}

void mouseReleased() {
  // remove the mouse attraction when button has been released
  //physics.removeBehavior(gestureAttractor);
}


///// OSC RECEIVING

void oscEvent(OscMessage theOscMessage) {
  /* check if theOscMessage has the address pattern we are looking for. */

  if (theOscMessage.checkAddrPattern("/gesture_classification") == true)  {
    /* check if the typetag is the right one. */
    if(theOscMessage.checkTypetag("i")) {
      /* parse theOscMessage and extract the values from the osc message arguments. */
      int gestureClassLabel = theOscMessage.get(0).intValue();  
      println(" Gesture is: ", gestureClassLabel);

      if (gestureClassLabel == 0){   
        resetAttraction();
      } else if (gestureClassLabel == 1) {       
        addAttraction();
      } else if (gestureClassLabel == 2) {
          //physics.removeBehavior(gestureAttractor);
      } 
    }  
  } 

}

//////METHODS FOR SETTING POSITION / REMOVAL OF ATTRACTORS...

void resetAttraction() {
  if (gestureAttractor != null){
      physics.removeBehavior(gestureAttractor);
      println("ATTRACTOR NULL");
     } else {
        println("not null");
     }
 }

void addAttraction(){
     if (gestureAttractor == null) {
         println("ATTRACTOR NULL");
         position1.set(340, 191);
         gestureAttractor = new AttractionBehavior2D(position1, 250, 0.9f);
         physics.addBehavior(gestureAttractor);
     } else {
       println("not null");
     }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the way you're looping here just after `physics.update();`, here:`for (VerletParticle2D p : physics.particles) {
    ellipse(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
  }`. Can you try using a plain old for loop ? `for (int i = 0 ; i < physics.particles.size() ; i++) {VerletParticle2D p = physics.particles.get(i);
    ellipse(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
  }`

Comment: can you paste the exception stacktrace?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, the behavior is still the same :/

Comment: Actually, trying to print the exception seemed to solve the problem @AbhijithNagarajan - will put the results in an answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You shouldn't modify a data structure with one thread while you're iterating over it from another thread.

The `draw()` function is happening on one thread, and it's accessing and modifying data structures inside the physics library.

The `oscEvent()` function is happening on another thread, and it's also accessing and modifying those same data structures. That's what's causing your error. And please note that wrapping it in a `try` block is **not** fixing anything. It's just printing out more information when the error does happen.

To really fix the problem, you need to read up on synchornizing data access between threads. For example, you could use synchronized blocks to prevent different threads from accessing the same data structure. You'll find a ton of results if you google your error.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - it looks as though the stuff in this thread on the Processing forum (which has some of your answers!) is what I want: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/5886/multithreading-madness